# FileStream to Bitmap - Parameter is not valid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have read the posts on this subject but none of them explains it to me clearly enough to be able to fix the problem.

I am trying to upload a file from a local directory to the server.

Here is my code:

```
string fullPath = Path.Combine(
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"Images\Readings", PhotoFileName);

Stream s = System.IO.File.OpenRead(fileUpload);

byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length];

s.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(s.Length));

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((Stream)fs);

    bmp.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

I keep on getting an Argument Exception: "Parameter is not valid" on line:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((Stream)fs);
```

Can anyone explain this to me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two problems, probably three. First, your copying code is broken:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length];
s.Read(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(s.Length));
```

You've *assumed* that this will read all of the data in a single `Read` call, and ignored the return value for `Read`. Generally, you'd need to loop round, reading data and writing it (the amount you've just read) to the output stream, until you read the end. However, as of .NET 4, `Stream.CopyTo` makes this much simpler.

Next is how you're creating the bitmap:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullPath, FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((Stream)fs);    
    bmp.Save(fs, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

You're trying to *read* from the stream when you've just written to it - but without "rewinding"... so there's no more data left to read.

Finally, I would strongly advise against using `Bitmap.Save` to write to the same stream that you're loading the bitmap from. `Bitmap` will keep a stream open, and read from it when it needs to - if you're trying to write to it at the same time, that could be very confusing.

It's not clear why you're using `Bitmap` at all, to be honest - if you're just trying to save the file that was uploaded, without any changes, just use:

```
using (Stream input = File.OpenRead(fileUpload),
              output = File.Create(fullPath))
{
    input.CopyTo(output);
}
```

This is assuming that `fileUpload` really is an appropriate filename - it's not clear why you haven't just written the file to the place you *want* to write it to straight away, to be honest. Or use [`File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to copy the file. The above code should work with *any* stream, so you can change it to save the stream straight from the request...